# Jquery to calculate total of table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to calculate the printing cost of when a customer makes an order of invitation.

If it was just 1 product in the basket its easy but in the example I've made the customer has 2 different invitation models and both have different printing options and cost.

I've made a custom js function based `onclick` action but for some reason it doesn't calculate correct Option cost.

I've prepared jsfidle below: Thank you for any help!

```js
function calculate_options() {
  $('.cart > tbody  > .product').each(function() {
    var thisrow = $(this).attr("id");
    var ttloptions = 0.0;
    if ($('.optradio').length) {
      var qty = parseInt($(this).find('.qty').val());
      var optamount = $('#' + thisrow).find('.optradio:checked').attr('data');
      console.log(optamount);
      var ttloptions = optamount * qty;
      $('#' + thisrow).find('.optcost').text('' + ttloptions.toFixed(2));
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

table.cart label.h15,
.optradio {
  float: left;
}

label.h15 {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 172px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="cart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Options</th>
      <th>Option cost</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1635" class="product">
      <td>Product 1</td>
      <td align="center"> <input type="number" min="20" name="qty[]" class="qty 1635" value="20"></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="price[]" readonly="true" class="price" maxlength="6" value="1.55"></td>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="row width100 left"><label class="h15">Print options</label><label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="0" data="0" name="print" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">No print</label><label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="1" data="0.50" name="print[]" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">Black print ($0.50) /piece</label>
          <label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="2" data="0.70" name="print[]" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">Color print ($0.70) /piece</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span class="optcost"></span></td>
      <td align="center"><span class="amount">$31.00</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="1620" class="product">
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td align="center"> <input type="number" min="20" name="qty[]" class="qty 1635" value="20"></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="price[]" readonly="true" class="price" maxlength="6" value="1.20"></td>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="row width100 left"><label class="h15">Print options</label><label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="0" data="0" name="print" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">No print</label><label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="1" data="0.30" name="print[]" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">Black print ($0.50) /piece</label>
          <label class="nobold h15"><input type="radio" value="2" data="0.70" name="print[]" onclick="calculate_options();" class="optradio">Color print ($0.70) /piece</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span class="optcost"></span></td>
      <td align="center"><span class="amount">$24.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle link?

Comment: Please  Run code snippet

Comment: I needed to edit some stuff and check :p

Comment: `.optradio` is in global context, use `find` to set the context at the relevant `tr`.

Comment: Mosh Feu I am using mate: $('#'+thisrow).find('.optradio:checked').attr('data');
I am browsing the current row

Comment: Varun on some reason I could not create jsfiddle, some error accured, you can see my try here https://jsfiddle.net/8ztep6qe/2/

Comment: The problem is with your radio buttons, all have the same name and i am able to select multiple at the same time, i guess that should not be happening?!

Comment: @thecore7 I'm talking about `if ($('.optradio').length) {`. Also, @varun is right. You need to set a different `name` attribute to each groups of radio buttons..

Comment: No need to get the id just to create a selector to look for the same row that you already have as `this`

Comment: @charlietfl In the first version of the fuction I did not used the id of the row but since there was a problem with the calculation I decided to make it more clear and added the id - it didn't help.. Did you run the code snippet to see how onclick it calculates current row and doesnt calculate correct for the second row..?

Comment: Why do you need to recalculate each row when only one row option is changed? Only deal with that row instance since it doesn't affect the other rows. Then if you need a total for all rows go through all rows afterwards and only get each row total to create grand total

Comment: @charlietfl I can explain you why mate :) This function is not only called by onclick action but also it is included in 2 other functions. This means it need to calculate all rows separately.. Holp this help !

Comment: But that is over complicating the business logic.Can do all this using one change handler for all the form controls on each row. Within that change handler you have row instance by using `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: Some products don't have options some have.. This function calculates total of options cost and another includes them in grand total.. The question is how but not why.. :)

Comment: So what. A simple `if(row.find(':radio').length)` covers that problem

Comment: no it doesn't help , you may need to run code snippet I provided..

Comment: Please run some tests here https://jsfiddle.net/8ztep6qe/3/

Comment: Take a look at this. Does everything for whole row using basically same amount of code as you have just for radios https://jsfiddle.net/sLdh7wfj/1

Comment: #charlietfl looks as it is working mate :) You can post this as an answer so I can accept it ! Thank you very much for your time ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just doing options cost calcs in one function, do everything for whole row in a single change handler. The trick is to make sure you isolate the row instance first, then always look for row specific elements using `find()` from that parent row

```
$('.product :input ').on('change', function(e) {
  // start by isolating row instance
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr.product'),
    // then use find() for the row specific elements
    qty = +$row.find('.qty').val(),
    price = +$row.find('.price').val(),
    $opt = $row.find(':radio:checked'),
    optamount = 0;
  if ($opt.length) {
    optamount += $opt.attr('data') * qty;
  }
  total = (qty * price + optamount).toFixed(2);

  $row.find('.optcost').text(optamount.toFixed(2))

  $row.find('.amount').text('$' + total)
    // trigger one change on each row on page load
}).filter('.qty').change();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sLdh7wfj/1/)

Note you need to fix the radio names so they match each other on a per row basis

Comment: Might need some minor tweaks but the basics are there and it's probably a whole lot less complex than what you were previously doing